# Print specific value of XML response

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code return XML response, i want to print only link that contain https

like this:

https://xxxx.xxxx.com/playback/presentation/5

Ex of response:

```
<playback>
<format>
<type>presentation</type>
<url>https://xxxx.xxxx.com/playback/presentation/5</url>
<processingTime>915</processingTime>
<length>0</length>
<size>114961</size>
<preview>
```

I tried this:

```
x = re.search("<url>.{45}", full_responsee).group()
xx = x.replace('<url>', '')
soup = xx
print(x)
```

But i need solution more simple.

Any kind of help please?

Comment: Do you need something simpler that also does not work?

Comment: In general it’s a bad idea to use regexp to search or edit XML; use an xml parser like ElementTree see the documentation there are many examples you can start from https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree#module-xml.etree.ElementTree

Comment: When I run it, I get `x = re.search("<url>.{110}", full_responsee).group()` `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @Scott Hunter it is working know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `url` element only appears once & without any attributes, this will do the trick:

```
full_responsee.split("<url>")[1].split("</url>")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ElementTree and do this

```python
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse(your-xml)
url = tree.find('playback/format/url')
print(url)
```

and if you want to change the value:

```python
tree.find('url').text = "newValue"
```

Comment: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<playback><format><type>presentation</type><url>https://xxxx.xxxx.com/playback/presentation/5</url>

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be tree = et.fromstring(your-xml). et.parse would work if the xml was from a file.

Comment: xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 181

Comment: Try with just url = tree.find('url').

Comment: only return None